# Spacy word embeddings for sentence

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, word-embeddings, spacy

Spacy offers [pre-trained vectors for words](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity). However I have notices that you can get vectors for sentences too:

```
spacy_nlp('hello I').has_vector == True
```

However I can't figure how it calculates the word2vecs from the sentences. I've tried:

```
spacy_nlp('hello I').vector == spacy_nlp('hello').vector + spacy_nlp('I').vector
```

> False

```
spacy_nlp('hello I').vector/spacy_nlp('hello I').vector_norm == spacy_nlp('hello').vector/spacy_nlp('hello').vector_norm + spacy_nlp('I').vector/spacy_nlp('I').vector_norm
```

> False

I can't seem to find or work out how spacy computes the w2v for sentences.

---

```
a =spacy_nlp('hello').vector
a

array([ 2.1919045 , -1.3554063 , -2.0530818 , -1.4123821 ,  0.73116064,
       -0.24243775, -1.238019  , -1.038872  , -3.8119905 ,  0.3023836 ,
        2.0082908 , -0.4146578 ,  0.52871764, -4.171281  , -4.014127  ,
        3.5551465 ,  3.5740273 ,  0.5369273 , -0.92361224,  1.4550962 ,
        2.1736908 , -0.05514041,  0.02151388, -2.1722403 ,  0.81322104,
        3.5877275 , -1.0136521 ,  4.6003613 , -0.19145766,  5.403145  ,
       -1.9958102 ,  0.80248785, -2.3566568 ,  2.15387   ,  0.26684093,
        1.8178961 ,  3.594517  , -2.9950802 ,  2.5587099 , -5.6746616 ,
       -3.7259517 ,  4.0144114 , -1.4814405 ,  1.5888698 , -0.2371515 ,
        0.5498152 ,  0.9527153 , -4.1197095 , -4.252441  , -0.36907774,
       -4.510469  ,  1.2669985 , -0.91693896, -3.0032263 , -4.037157  ,
       -1.986922  ,  1.8322158 , -0.9520336 , -2.6739838 ,  0.368276  ,
        0.5881702 ,  1.4819605 ,  2.1771026 ,  0.20011072, -0.20952749,
       -1.7966032 ,  4.412916  , -0.8781664 ,  3.0670204 ,  3.92986   ,
       -0.7381511 , -0.07432494, -3.6973615 , -3.546731  ,  1.6010978 ,
       -4.0834403 ,  1.7816883 ,  0.8037724 ,  0.40344352, -1.2090104 ,
       -3.3253288 ,  4.6769385 ,  1.3193885 , -1.1775286 , -1.2436512 ,
       -0.29471165,  1.9998071 ,  1.1338542 ,  5.747326  , -0.10331005,
        1.6050186 ,  2.6961374 , -1.9422164 , -3.0807574 , -1.1481779 ,
        7.1367517 ], dtype=float32)

b =spacy_nlp('I').vector
b

array([ 1.9940598e+00, -2.7776110e+00,  8.4717870e-01, -2.1956882e+00,
       -1.6103275e+00,  1.2993972e-01,  8.3826280e-01,  8.7950850e-01,
       -3.5490465e+00,  4.4254961e+00, -1.4894485e+00,  4.4692218e-01,
       -6.0040636e+00,  3.4809113e-01,  7.5852954e-01, -5.0149399e-01,
       -1.9669157e+00,  8.8114321e-01,  5.3964740e-01,  1.6436796e+00,
       -4.3819084e+00,  7.1328688e-01, -8.9688343e-01, -1.2563754e+00,
       -2.6987386e-01,  3.3273227e+00,  7.1929336e-01,  1.2008041e-01,
        2.8758078e+00, -8.6590099e-01,  5.6435466e-01, -5.4331255e-01,
       -3.3853512e+00, -2.0917976e+00, -1.1649452e+00,  8.6632729e+00,
        9.1355121e-01, -3.9117950e-01, -6.3341379e-01, -3.4170332e+00,
        3.2871642e+00,  4.5229197e-03, -4.0161700e+00,  2.6399128e+00,
       -2.4242992e+00, -1.2012237e-01, -1.1977488e-01, -1.6422987e-01,
        7.7170479e-01, -1.5015860e+00, -3.0203837e-01,  1.9385589e+00,
       -2.9229348e+00, -2.8134599e+00, -6.1340892e-01, -2.5029099e+00,
       -6.6817325e-01, -8.4735197e-01,  4.2243872e+00,  2.8358276e+00,
       -2.7096636e+00,  6.3791027e+00,  1.3461562e+00, -3.9387980e+00,
        1.0648534e+00,  5.3636909e-01,  4.1285772e+00, -2.8879738e+00,
        1.3546917e+00, -1.9005369e+00, -3.7411542e+00, -4.8598945e-02,
       -1.4411114e+00,  1.3436056e+00,  1.1946709e+00,  2.3972931e+00,
        2.1032238e+00,  1.8248746e+00, -2.1880054e+00, -1.4601905e+00,
       -1.9771397e+00,  9.3115008e-01, -3.7088573e+00, -4.9041757e-01,
        1.0846795e+00,  2.2863836e+00,  3.5038524e+00,  1.0964345e+00,
        3.6875091e+00, -1.6266774e+00,  1.4012933e-02,  2.7396250e+00,
        3.9477596e+00, -3.5737205e+00,  3.1862993e+00,  2.2955155e+00],
      dtype=float32)

c =spacy_nlp('hello I').vector
c

array([ 2.4846857 , -1.9697192 , -0.09456831, -1.5198507 , -1.6889997 ,
       -0.7867774 , -1.1812011 ,  0.01011622, -2.9120972 ,  3.59254   ,
        1.3454058 , -0.305678  , -2.1474035 , -3.110804  , -0.6446719 ,
        1.9236953 ,  0.88007987,  0.4077559 ,  0.27990723,  0.36027157,
        1.214731  , -0.27636862,  0.33037317, -1.4009418 , -1.7570219 ,
        2.0057924 ,  0.1711272 ,  0.65295005, -0.6732832 ,  1.5165039 ,
       -1.8387947 , -0.49002886, -2.529176  ,  1.0543746 ,  0.13975173,
        6.3513803 ,  3.1074045 , -1.8838222 ,  1.707653  , -3.5569887 ,
        0.02888358,  1.4662569 , -1.4711913 ,  1.6238092 , -0.996526  ,
        0.29157495,  0.7459268 , -2.6089895 , -1.4595604 , -1.6607146 ,
       -1.9626031 ,  0.0429309 , -2.2927856 , -2.7657444 , -2.2093186 ,
       -1.8635755 ,  1.1076405 , -0.87808686, -0.8882728 , -0.20140225,
       -0.14074779,  1.5494955 ,  2.2195954 , -0.8879056 ,  0.16175044,
       -0.47926584,  6.069929  , -2.2804523 ,  1.389133  ,  2.3614829 ,
       -1.6746982 , -0.65907   , -0.88322634, -0.35415757,  1.2424103 ,
       -1.3832704 ,  1.74179   ,  2.0219522 , -0.3940425 , -1.076731  ,
       -3.0649443 ,  2.6106696 , -0.03948617,  0.03465301,  0.6218431 ,
        0.8250919 ,  1.7428303 ,  0.8449378 ,  3.0572054 ,  0.29650444,
        0.4229828 ,  0.38575757,  0.20896101, -0.91772854,  0.3865456 ,
        4.248111  ], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

To construct sentence embeddings Spacy just averages the word embeddings. I do not have access to Spacy right now, else would have give a demonstration but you can try:

```
spacy_nlp('hello I').vector == (spacy_nlp('hello').vector + spacy_nlp('I').vector) / 2
```

If this also gives `False`, it will be because the float values might not be exactly equal after the computation. So, just print them out separately and you will see that they are really close.

Comment: I have tried averaging them but they are quite far apart still.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the values for vectors?

Comment: See the edited post

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **average embeddings of the parsed tokens**.
Mind that the tokenizer may be customized/different from what you expect.

Here you find a full example

```
import spacy
import numpy as np

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
txt= 'ChatGPT could automatically compose comments submitted in regulatory processes. It could write letters to the editor for publication in local newspapers. It could comment on news articles, blog entries and social media posts millions of times every day." https://t.co/rXL8WgJ4hV'

vec1 = nlp(txt).vector
vec2 = np.array([t.vector for t in nlp(txt)]).mean(0)

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(vec1,vec2)
```